# Providing library to users without source code?

Tags: java

I have created a library that can do some work. I want users to use it, but due to certain reasons (having some secret recipes in it), I don't want users of library to see the source code. It is possible ? One option is providing output via json , but that is not feasible due to infrastructure requirement. (this question is after my understanding that .class files can be decompiled to java code.

Comment: you can use Obfuscators to make it hard to decompile your .class file...

Comment: check this http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can make it harder (obfuscation etc.) but AFAIK you cannot prevent it.

Legally: make clear under what license you distribute your library.